# Cross domain GET JSON encoded string?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I have an app that I'm writing in Javascript for use with Phonegap, that retrieves a JSON encoded string from a PHP script on my server.

Is it possible to retrieve this JSON encoded string from the PHP in Javascript when it's a cross domain request?

What I'm currently using is Yahoo's YQL, which retrieves the string through a jQuery AJAX, but I don't want to have to rely on Yahoo for their service, especially since it's been very flakey today in terms of uptime.

Comment: is it a GET request to load your "JSON encoded string from a PHP script on my server" ? I.e. can't you just use jsonp?

Comment: Are you sure phonegap enforces same-origin policy for cross domain calls? My understanding is that they didn't, because the app is run via "localhost

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For Cross Domain GET's, if you own the endpoint, I recommend modifying it to use [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP)

Because browser `<script>` tags can load scripts from different domains, it is one way to work around cross-domain issues, with little worry about cross-browser support. It does pose some potential Cross-Site-Scripting Issues (I recommend reading the wiki page I linked above) that you should be aware of.

Make JSONP API calls is super easy if you use `jQuery`, but it's still simple enough to do with strict javascript by dynamically injecting the `<script>` tags yourself, setting the `src` attribute to your API endpoint, and creating your own callback function that is invoked once the call is successful.

Modify your server endpoint to take a `callback` parameter. Wrap your json response with the callback.

e.g. (not real code)

```
//example api url
//http://tempuri/apiendpoint?callback=foo 

//example url handler (not in PHP)
app.get('/apiendpoint',function() {
  return query.callback + '({"json": "value"});'
});
```

If you'd rather not support JSONP, you can enable Cross Origin Resource Sharing (CORS). Both iOS and Android webbrowsers support it. In order to add support for CORS, you'll need to modify your endpoint to send the appropriate headers:

```
'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'
'Access-Control-Allow-Methods'
'Access-Control-Allow-Headers'
```

Comment: This was really the easiest solution. If anyone has trouble getting this to work, follow this guide (it helped me) http://www.fbloggs.com/2010/07/09/how-to-access-cross-domain-data-with-ajax-using-jsonp-jquery-and-php/

Answer (score 0):

There is a Perl script called ACD (AJAX Cross Domain) that I've used quite successfully in the past - check it out [here](http://www.ajax-cross-domain.com). The best part is that you don't have to rely on an external service.

It works like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://my-domain.com/cgi-bin/ACD/ACD.js?uri=(http://www.google.com)"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
 alert(ACD.responseText); //Should alert the source of google.com
</script>
```

Comment: Is the Perl script run on the server side or client side though?